# PaypalAndroid SDK Error

Tags: android, paypal-sandbox, paypal

I tried to integrate **PaypalAndroid SDK 2.8.5** into my Android App. The Single Payment is working fine when the configuration is set to

> PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK,

But the app crashes when I set the Payment Configuration as follows:

> PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX
>   PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION

Here is the complete Source:

```
package com.example.paypaltestingapp;

import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalAuthorization;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalItem;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalOAuthScopes;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPaymentDetails;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalProfileSharingActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.ShippingAddress;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Basic sample using the SDK to make a payment or consent to future payments.
 * 
 * For sample mobile backend interactions, see
 * https://github.com/paypal/rest-api
 * -sdk-python/tree/master/samples/mobile_backend
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "paymentExample";

    Button buyItBtn;

    /**
     * - Set to PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION to move real money.
     * 
     * - Set to PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX to use your test
     * credentials from https://developer.paypal.com
     * 
     * - Set to PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK to kick the tires
     * without communicating to PayPal's servers.
     */
    private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION;

    // note that these credentials will differ between live & sandbox
    // environments.
    private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "CLIENT ID";

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_SHARING = 3;

    private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
            .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT).clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
    // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
    ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);

        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

        startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onBuyPressed(View pressed) {

        // PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE will cause the payment to complete immediately.
        // Change PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE to
        // - PAYMENT_INTENT_AUTHORIZE to only authorize payment and capture
        // funds later.
        // - PAYMENT_INTENT_ORDER to create a payment for authorization and
        // capture
        // later via calls from your server.

        PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("1.75"),
                "USD", "sample item", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);

        // send the same configuration for restart resiliency
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            PaymentConfirmation confirm = data
                    .getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if (confirm != null) {
                try {
                    Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));

                    // TODO: send 'confirm' to your server for verification.
                    // see
                    // https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/
                    // for more details.

                    Log.e(TAG, confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                    Log.e(TAG, confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject().toString(4));

                    String paymentId = confirm.toJSONObject()
                            .getJSONObject("response").getString("id");

                    String payment_client = confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject()
                            .toString();

                    Log.e(TAG, "paymentId: " + paymentId + ", payment_json: "
                            + payment_client);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("paymentExample",
                            "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                }
            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.i("paymentExample", "The user canceled.");
        } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
            Log.i("paymentExample",
                    "An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted. Please see the docs.");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: stacktrace including the line that throws the exception?

Comment: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-java before you start developing on Android. Sorry pal but if you don't know what a stack trace is, you're way over your head.

Comment: CAN YOU GIVE SOLUTION?

Comment: Look at your log viewer (logcat) for the exception stacktrace.

Comment: @kichik it's showing empty, nothing to view?